# Python extract text between regex matches

Tags: python, regex

I have a text file that I want to extract data from using Python. An example of the file is as follows:

```
123
text I want to extract is here. 
456
I also need this part
789
and this
```

Now, if I use a regular expression as follows:

```
re.match(r'^(\d){3}$', text)
```

I can get the numbers, however, I would want to get the text between the numbers. I know I can use re.split, but if I do re.split with the same expression i.e.

```
re.split(r'^(\d){3}$', text)
```

it will split it as follows:

```
['123', 'text I want to extract is here. 456 I also need this part 789 and this']
```

The outcome I want to obtain is instead, this:

```
['text I want to extract is here.','I also need this part', 'and this']
```

Any advice on how to achieve this?

Thanks!

**EDIT**: I realise that there are ways to match exactly the text between the numbers. However, my example is more complex in reality and there is no easy way to write a regex match for the text in between the numbers. This is why I am interested in knowing whether the regex match of the numbers can be used to extract the text in between them.

Comment: You need `flags=re.MULTILINE` so that `^` and `$` match beginning/end of lines, not beginning/end of the string.

Comment: Your result of the split has unmatched quotes.

Comment: Your output cannot be the one you showed, see [your `re.split` demo](https://ideone.com/U3UiTs).

Comment: Since you are reading from a file, have you considered filtering the lines with the regex instead of trying to split the whole thing? Something like `[line.strip() for line in file if not rx.match(line)]` with `rx` being the compliled regex you started with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the line after the 3 digits, and that line should not start with a digit you can use a capture group:

```
^\d{3}((?:\n(?!\d{3}$).*)*)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ItXeRN/1)

**Example**

```
import re

pattern = r"^\d{3}((?:\n(?!\d{3}$).*)*)"

s = ("123\n"
            "text I want to extract is here. \n"
            "and this is some more text\n"
            "456\n"
            "I also need this part\n"
            "789\n"
            "and this ")

result = [x.strip() for x in re.findall(pattern, s, re.M)]
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
['text I want to extract is here. \nand this is some more text', 'I also need this part', 'and this']
```

Comment: thanks for the answer - however I am not looking for a regex match of the text between the numbers, but rather if the regex match of the numbers can be used to extract what comes in between. This is because in reality the file is much more complicated. I have edited the question

Comment: @AmyD I have updated the answer to get the text between the digits.

Answer (score 0):

here is one way to it

```
txt="""123
text I want to extract is here. 
456
I also need this part
789
and this""" 

s=re.findall(r'(\D*)', txt)
[i.strip()  for i in s if i != ""]
```

Result

```
['text I want to extract is here.', 'I also need this part', 'and this']
```

Comment: thank you - however I am not looking for a regex match of the text between the numbers, but rather if the regex match of the numbers that is in my question can be used to extract what comes in between matches. This is because in reality the file is much more complicated than what I have in the example. I have edited the question